# Use another container inside of the other

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I started using docker and I have created a basic `docker-compose.yml` file. The problem I am facing currently is that I have multiple containers that need to be one. My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: devmyoy123
    ports:
      - "27017:27017" 

  node:
    container_name: node
    image: node
    volumes:
      - ./node/:/var/app/node
    environment:
      REDIS_URI: redis://redis:6379
    links:
      - mongodb
      - redis
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

  httpd:
    container_name: httpd
    image: php:7.2-apache
    volumes:
      - ./api/:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
    environment:
      REDIS_URI: redis://redis:6379
    links:
      - mongodb
      - redis
      - node
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

I need a way to use `node` inside the `httpd` container and I also need the `mongodb` and `redis` parameters inside of `httpd` and `node` containers.

Comment: Your Docker Compose file looks fine, and in particular the way you're passing the Redis location across to the other containers is good.  I would not try to run this in fewer containers.  What actual issue are you encountering?

Comment: @DavidMaze I am trying to run `node` inside of the `httpd` container

Comment: Why?  (Especially given that it's already running a PHP process.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I am running Laravel inside of the `httpd` container and I want to compile my assets using `node`

Comment: @DavidMaze have you tried compile your assets and then copy the result into your httpd image? I´m talking about multi stage building here. https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: @OscarNevarez I am not copying files into my image, instead I am using volumes